# What is the tape-like stuff being applied to the cooling assembly for this laptop?

Tags: cpu, fan, thermal-paste

By googling for while, I was not able to find an answer to the question that arose after watching this video:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=KsW1DURTHco#t=2055

(The link should bring you immediately to the part of the movie, at 34:16, where this is being done)

In this part of video the guy starts cutting some material, that later apply to fan part between chips and itself? what is this material? Does it have the same properties as usual thermal paste?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They look like thermal pads to me. They help dissipate any heat that is produced by the components they are placed on.

If you Google search `Thermal Pads` you will find plenty of links.

Comment: Ok that's it! Thanks a lot! This is cheaper alternative to thermal paste then.
Thank you one more time, there was no way I was finding that term.

Comment: Thermal pads are only used for components that are not likely to generate much heat and thus are less likely to overheat. CPU's, GPU's and other hotter components will still need thermal paste.